How to input actions from asset browser?
I want to input actions from asset browser just by drag and drop like other assets.
What I do:

make a simple move action on a cube, mark the action as asset, so I can see the action in asset browser.
create a new blend file, make a sphere, open asset browser, drag the cube action, but no place allow me to drop it down, the action data can't be input into the new file.

I know that append actions works, but there's no meaning to mark actions as assets.

I think action assets work for bones, not objects, so it won't work as you expect.
